# Detect if the mouse cursor is hidden or visible by any other application

Tags: python, c, windows, mouse

I want to detect if the mouse is currently hidden, something that is often done by 3D applications on Windows. This appears to be trickier than it sounds as I can't find any way to do this.

Preferably I want to do this using Python but if that's not possible I could resort to C. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`GetCursorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function returns a [`CURSORINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure that has a `flags` field that contains the global cursor state. Would this do what you need? I'm not familiar with Python so I don't know if you can call this function from Python.

Comment: Thank you, that worked excellent and is callable from python. http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32gui__GetCursorInfo_meth.html

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to call the [`GetCursorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  This can be done straightforwardly using the [pywin32 library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).  Or, if you'd rather not install external Python libraries, you can use the [`ctypes` module](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) to directly access the function from User32.dll.

Example:

```
import ctypes

# Argument structures
class POINT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', ctypes.c_int),
                ('y', ctypes.c_int)]

class CURSORINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('cbSize', ctypes.c_uint),
                ('flags', ctypes.c_uint),
                ('hCursor', ctypes.c_void_p),
                ('ptScreenPos', POINT)]

# Load function from user32.dll and set argument types
GetCursorInfo = ctypes.windll.user32.GetCursorInfo
GetCursorInfo.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(CURSORINFO)]

# Initialize the output structure
info = CURSORINFO()
info.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(info)

# Call it
if GetCursorInfo(ctypes.byref(info)):
    if info.flags & 0x00000001:
        pass  # The cursor is showing
else:
    pass  # Error occurred (invalid structure size?)
```